# Three.js not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I have been doing some experiments with three.js. However, when I try to do a simple test, I can't get it to display anything. Here's my code. If someone could tell me what I'm missing it would be really helpful.

```
//Constant declaration
var RENDER_DIST = 1000,
    FOV = 75;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT= window.innerHeight;

//Create the scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Create the camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, RENDER_DIST);

//Pull the camera back a bit
camera.z = 100;
//Then add it to the scene
scene.add(camera);

//Create a renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
renderer.domElement.className = "glMain";

//Container is a div
$("#container").html(renderer.domElement);

//Boilerplate done! Celebrate!
(function init() {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50); 
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000}); 
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 
    scene.add(sphere);

    //debugging
    console.log("Sphere at " + sphere.position.x + " " + sphere.position.y + " " + sphere.position.z);


})();

//Our main function
(function loopRun() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loopRun);

    console.log("rendered");
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

On the console log I am getting all the `"rendered"` messages but nothing is displaying. I have checked that the canvas is the right size and it is, so I have no idea what is wrong. I have tried a few different geometries.

EDIT: I am using Chrome, and online three.js examples work fine. There are no errors on the console log.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//Pull the camera back a bit
camera.position.z = 100;

//Container is a div
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Yep! That was it. Dynamic typing seems to have a grudge against me today.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try :

```
$("#container").append(renderer.viewElement);
```